# Github: Can't remove my database from tracked list

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git and I have a database in my project directory and  don't want to push in into my remote repository. I've tried `git rm --cached <database name>` but I received this error.

```
error: the following file has staged content different from both the file and the HEAD:
    Mydb.db
(use -f to force removal)
```

I want to know what's the cause of that? Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please include screenshot of `git status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do this is to make a `.gitignore` file.

Include this in the file:

```
*.db
```

[How to use Gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

---

Apart from the above, to answer your doubt, it will not be pushed to your git repo until you do `git add {DB FILE NAME}`